# How to restore output from pg_dump into a new table name

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am dumping a large Postgres table like this:

```bash
pg_dump -h myserver  -U mt_user --table=mytable  -Fc -Z 9 --file mytable.dump mydb
```

The above creates a `mytable.dump` file. I now want to restore this dump into a new table called `mytable_restored`.

How can I use the `pg_restore` command to do this?

Answer (score 14):

There is no `pg_restore` option to rename tables.

I would do it like this:

```
-- create a table that is defined like the original
CREATE TABLE mytable_restored (LIKE mytable INCLUDING ALL);

-- copy the table contents
COPY mytable TO '/tmp/mytable.dmp';
COPY mytable_restored FROM '/tmp/mytable.dmp';
```

Comment: I guess this is the easiest way to do

Comment: Is the COPY step faster than just doing `INSERT INTO mytable_restored (SELECT * from mytable)`?   I suppose it is possible that COPY rebuilds the index at the end instead of incrementally updating it, but it also requires writing the temp data to a file.

Comment: @ScottCarey `COPY` will modify the index row by row, but it won't write temporary files.

Comment: When I say temporary files, I mean the `/tmp/mytable.dmp` file in the example here.  That is extra I/O that does not happen with INSERT INTO ... (SELECT * from ...).   For very large tables, that can be a large difference.

Comment: @ScottCarey You are right. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: This is a shame.  I'm looking to departition some tables, and dumping in parallel would speed the process, even if I'll have to load in sequence.

Comment: @RonJohn You can `COPY (SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ...) TO '...'` in several parallel processes.

Comment: Sure, but that manual process requires much manual planning that postgresql can more expertly do, and already has an infrastructure for.

Answer (score 1):

you can append sed to your pg_dump so that while pg_dump outputs the table name, sed will replace it with the right one.

```
pg_dump mytable mydb | sed 's/mytable/mytable_restored/g' > mytable_restored.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not the exact answer for the question but for my case (directory dump with many tables),  I have improved Laurenz's answer, it may be useful.
In my case I have just needed two tables  to restore to another location. 
First I created the tables in new location.
I find the table data in the toc.dat file.

```
pg_restore -Fd <dir_name> -l | grep <table_name>
```

This will probably return more than single line. Then we look for "TABLE DATA" line. After getting [file_number].dat.gz file and use it in copy command like below in psql.

```
COPY <table_name> from PROGRAM 'zcat /<path>/<file_number>.dat.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PG-13, there is no built-in way, but if you are using Unix-ish system and perl is installed, I have simple solution below which should work as long as table-names do not contains spaces.

Go into your dump directory and run

```
 pg_restore -l -Fd .  |
 perl -ln -e '$Z=".gz";' -e 'print qq(mv "$1.dat$Z" "$3.sql$Z") if /^(\d+);.* TABLE DATA (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)$/'
```

Change `"$Z=".gz"` accordingly depending on the system's compressed filename-extensions (or set to empty string when dumping with `--compress=0`).

If the results look ok, run again, and pipe the whole thing through the shell, ie, `| /bin/sh`.